# Bash commands don't work after changing Path variable

Tags: linux, macos, bash, command

I'm unable to use ls, bash.. any popular commands that are critical after changing the path.
I'm unsure what it was before (because I can't do vi command either).
I ran the first command, and realized the first one had a typo - not PATH, but I've typed PATh.
So I immediately ran the next one:

```
export PATH="/usr/local/bin:$PATh"
export PATH="/usr/local/bin:$PATH"
```

Then vi, ls, bash commands started to not work.

I did echo $PATH to see the PATH.

```
usr/local/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/bin:
```

This is what I got. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: `PATH=$(getconf PATH)`

Comment: If you didn't actually edit any files, the change is only local to the current shell session. Just logout and start a new shell.

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to `source /etc/profile` to reset your PATH variable, though it may step on a few other variables you've configured along the way.  You could also just grep for the appropriate line from that to set `PATH` and redo that in your current environment

Also, you can always specify the full path to an executable you need in the interim.  For example, if you wanted to use `grep` with the PATH in its current state you could use `/bin/grep` (or perhaps `/usr/bin/grep` depending your system)

Answer (score 1):

I had the same in RHEL8, I did an export PATH for a certain directory and then no command worked anymore. I performed a faulty ***export PATH*** command probably.

I got messages like this:

```
>$ yum
bash: yum: command not found...
Install package 'yum' to provide command 'yum'? [N/y] n
```

Luckily I had some other similar systems where I could get the path from, so I did:

```
export PATH=/home/USER/.local/bin:/home/USER/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/sbine
```

Change USER to your own.

To make it permanent: add to $HOME/.bashrc with:

```
export PATH=$PATH:<YOUR PATH HERE>
```

Answer (score 0):

1 > Try to load default .profile script

```
$ /bin/bash ./.profile
```

2 > Just Logout from current session 
and Re-login it.

Answer (score 0):

It appears you have "broken" your bash shell ~/.bash_profile script, because of the `PATh` typo.  (The question explicitly states `bash`, so I'm answering in that context.)

Since the PATH is "broken", you will need to access your editor by using its fully qualified path.

```
/usr/bin/vi ~/.bash_profile
```

That should allow you to fix the `PATh` to be `PATH`.

If you find that you need to edit your PATH environment variable a lot, this little `bash` function can be helpful.

```
vipath() {
  local tmpfile=$(mktemp /tmp/vipath-edit.XXXXXX)
  echo "$PATH" | tr ':' '\n' > "$tmpfile"
  vi "$tmpfile" && PATH=$(paste -s -d ':' "$tmpfile")
  rm "$tmpfile"
}
```

Note: there are better ways to ensure the $tmpfile gets deleted that I did not use in this snippet.  And on a multiuser system, there are better ways to make sure the temporary file is not located in a shared location.

If you want to add a directory location to your PATH, without adding duplicate locations, this little `bash` function can be helpful to prepend a directory location.

```
pathadd() {
  if [ -d "$1" ] && [[ ! ":$PATH:" =~ ":$1:" ]]
  then
    PATH="$1:$PATH"
  fi  
}
```

Answer (score -2):

When you do `export PATH="/usr/local/bin:$PATH"` you are saying, set PATH to /usr/local/bin: plus whatever was in the PATH variable before.  This essentially concatenates the string "/usr/local/bin:" with the old path.  That is why your PATH repeats so much, you must have run that command a few times.

Try running this: `export PATH="/usr/local/bin"`.

Comment: As they noted in the question, the problem they're having is from having a typo when reassigning `PATH` which caused them to lose all the original path.  So what you talked about could come into play, but isn't really the problem at hand.